# How do I send email through gmail with cforms?

Tags: wordpress, email, forms, smtp

I want to [use gmail as the SMTP server](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=29121&forum=43) when sending email with [cforms](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/).

Comment: This is probably not what you're thinking about...but if you transfer your domain to google to domain Google will *probably* be your smtp server: www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new

Answer (score 1):

I havent used this plugin, but as being the wordpress plugin developer, I guess there should be a setting section to set the smtp host and port. To add the gmail correct smtp host and port please check this article http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77659